# jQuery validate select fields conditionally

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I need to be able to conditionally require certain fields to be validated, based on the contents of a specific select field. For example, I have the following select:

```
<select name="new_jobType">
<option value="">Please select</option>
<option value="1">option 1</option>
<option value="2">option 2</option>
<option value="3">option 3</option>
<option value="4">option 4</option>
</select>
```

If 'option 4' is selected, I need to include 5-6 other select fields to be validated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might do something like this:

```
var validations = new Array();

$('select[name="new_jobType"]').change(function() {
    var thisJob = $(this + " option:selected").val();

    if(thisJob == 4) {
        validations.push("thisJobValidations");
    }
});
```

Just push any validation routines that need to run onto that validations array, and then on submit:

```
for(var i = 0; i < validations.length; i++) {
    eval(validations[i] + "();");
}
```

And you would have function(s) to do the actual validations:

```
function thisJobValidations() {
    // validation magic happens here
}
```

The `eval()` inside the for loop will execute the validation routine(s) based on what had been pushed onto the `validations` array.

That way you can segment your validations based on what conditions had been met, and you don't have to write one monolithic validation function that would be more error-prone.

Encapsulate all the things!! :-)